# Installed Octave 4.2.1 with brew on MacOS; can't get it to run with a GUI

Tags: macos, user-interface, homebrew, octave

I installed Octave on my macOS Sierra using Homebrew with the command

```
brew install octave
```

and everything installed fine.

When I run Octave, however, it prints version 4.2.1, but I do not get the GUI nor can I force the GUI with `octave --force-gui`. No error message or warning is generated, the app just starts in the command line.

How do I get Octave to run with a GUI?

Comment: try reinstalling Octave with `brew reinstall octave --with-qt --with-fltk --with-gui`

Comment: I tried that but got warnings like this: octave: this formula has no --with-gui option so it will be ignored!

Comment: btw what version of Mac OSX Sierra do you have ?

Comment: Mac Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: You may find [***this***](http://normnorris.com/installing-octave-4-2-1-on-macos-sierra/) helpful

Comment: @SardarUsama Where did you get these options? None of those exist on the `octave` formula.

Comment: @bfontaine https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/121525/cant-start-octave-3-8-0-in-gui-mode

Comment: @SardarUsama Thanks. I guess they existed at some point then got removed.

Comment: I decided to uninstall octave using brew and reinstalled it using MacPort.  All works fine now.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: See here https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/15986

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run brew uninstall octave to removed the octave executables. Use MacPort instead of homebrew. Run 'port selfupgrade' and then 'port install octave'. It installs octave in the opt/local/bin directory. Type octave and it runs with the GUI. Version 4.2.1 was installed and seems to work fine.

Comment: I also ran into the same brew issue and macports also worked for me for v4.2.2. I'm on High Sierra.

Comment: I was following these steps but when trying to 'port install octave' I get an error message: "Error: Unable to open port: no such compiler: clang36"

Comment: I am not aware of any problems or what the error message means.  I assume you updated MacPorts.  Do you have gcc installed.

Comment: it should be port selfupdate as shown in comment by dvallejo above.

Answer (score 2):

Try running the command `octave --gui` instead of `octave --force-gui`.